# Black & white effect/filter

Tags: swift, uiimage, core-image

I have UIImage and I would like to change it to black & white picture, or if you know how to do some other filters I would also appreciate it. For example: chrome filter(with nice colours).

Most of the codes I have already found are in objective-c, which I do not understand a lot.

Right now I am using this code to give it some effects.

```
func applyFilter() {        
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: tempImageView.image!)        
    let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]                
    let filteredImage = inputImage!.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)           
    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent)           
    tempImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)      
}
```

it works , but effects are terrible.

Thanks.

Comment: There are some easy-to-use filters in Core Image, I recommend this tutorial by Paul Hudson:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/13/overview

Comment: You could check my Filterpedia app (https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia) which demonstrates almost every available Core Image filter and a whole load of custom filters too!